# Spring Boot externalized configuration not working on Windows?

Tags: spring-boot

I set up a Spring Boot 1.3.0 application according to the reference guide http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files. All is working fine on OS X. The `application.properties` file is loaded from the current directory. The `@Value` expressions are resolved properly.

On Windows Server 2008 R2 / Java 1.8 however Spring barfs: `Could not resolve placeholder 'database.name' in string value "${database.name}"`. Apparently the properties file is not found/loaded.

Comment: I created a sample project with starter web and setted `database.name` I have been able to get the property using @Value("${database.name}") on a Bean parameter, I'm running on Windows 10. Are you settings the property on `application.properties` or on another file?

Comment: Yes the file is called `application.properties`.

Comment: Might it be some configuration about files on Windows Server ? I posted the sample [here](https://github.com/joaoevangelista/community-anwsers/tree/master/so-33739176) there is nothing special, maybe it's os and file path/security related instead of Spring.

Comment: Apparently there was some kind of clash between Java versions on this server. After removal of older versions the application starts fine.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there was some kind of clash between Java versions on this server. After removal of older versions the application starts fine.